# DAX - Filter Table by Multi Select Filter Condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

Am trying to filter a table with Multi Selection Filter.

DAX: To select the values in the filter selected (Multi)

```
SelectedEnvironments =
CONCATENATEX (
    VALUES ( Environments[ShortEnvName] ),
    Environments[ShortEnvName],
    ", "
)
```

Result:

[image]

But when trying to filter table based on above filter variable doesnt return anything.

DAX:

```
Aggregated Usage =
VAR __SelectedEnvironments =
    CONCATENATEX (
        VALUES ( Environments[ShortEnvName] ),
        Environments[ShortEnvName],
        ", "
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        LastestDBUsage,
        LastestDBUsage[Environment] IN { __SelectedEnvironments }
    )
```

If I hard code the values within `IN` operator it work fine.  What am doing wrong?  Do I need to format the string for `IN` operator

DAX (Works fine with Hard Code Values)

Aggregated Usage =

```
VAR __SelectedEnvironments =
    CONCATENATEX (
        VALUES ( Environments[ShortEnvName] ),
        Environments[ShortEnvName],
        ", "
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        LastestDBUsage,
        LastestDBUsage[Environment] IN { "DEV", "TST" }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `IN` operator works on tables, `CONCATENATEX` returns a string.

```
{ __SelectedEnvironments }
```

returns a table with one row consisting of one column like for instance "DEV, TST"

to make the code work it would be changed to use a table instead, like for instance

```
Aggregated Usage =
VAR __SelectedEnvironments = VALUES ( Environments[ShortEnvName] )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        LastestDBUsage,
        LastestDBUsage[Environment] IN __SelectedEnvironments
    )
```